# Ubuntu 15.10 mysql error 1524 - unix_socket

Tags: server, mysql

On Ubuntu 15.10, at a point (maybe after an install & remove of mariadb) mysql was unable to operate. Tasks are up, but the server is down.

At the command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

the system reply with like a:

```
mysql "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded"
```

No way to log in, no plugin found, no errors in config files (all to default).

How to get back in control, and make mysql server run?

Comment: I am not familiar with this particular error but see this discussion: https://lists.launchpad.net/maria-developers/msg08177.html

Comment: @Jos: that discussion, maybe for a similar situation, doesn't offer a solution. I've googled a lot, but I've not found a complete solution exposed. Anyway, I've posted a working answer.

Comment: About the reason for the error message: The unix_socket plugin is part of MariaDB (not MySQL) and needs to be loaded in order for grants using it to work: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The "unix_socket" has been called by mysql authentication process (maybe related to a partial migration of database to mariadb, now removed). To get all stuff back working go su:

```
sudo su
```

then follow:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot
```

This will completely stop mysql, bypass user authentication (no password needed) and connect to mysql with user "root".

Now, in mysql console, go using mysql administrative db:

```
use mysql;
```

To reset root password to *mynewpassword* (change it at your wish), just to be sure of it:

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
```

And this one will overwrite authentication method, remove the unix_socket request (and everything else), restoring a normal and working password method:

```
update user set plugin="mysql_native_password";
```

Exit mysql console:

```
quit;
```

Stop and start everything related to mysql:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
kill -9 $(pgrep mysql)
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Don't forget to `exit` the su mode.

Now mySQL server is up and running. You can login it with root:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

or whatever you wish. Password usage is operative.

That's it.

Comment: My `mysqld_safe` has no option like `--skip-grant-tables` ..what gives?

Comment: I'm on mysqld 5.6.27-0ubuntu1. You should find that option looking at: `mysqld --verbose --help`

Comment: This got me going. With some differences instead of `mysqld_safe` which complained the argument --skip-grant-tables didn't exist I used `mysqld`. However it kept complaining it couldn't create the socket files in `/var/run/mysqld/`. I checked the apparmor config and it had the proper permissions. To fix this I had to `mkdir /var/run/mysqld/` and then give completely open permissions: `chmod -R 777 /var/run/mysqld/`. Then I could finally start the daemon and change the plugin to 'mysql_native_password'.

Comment: My user table has no password field (Ubuntu 16 mysql 5.7.13). I used this SQL: UPDATE mysql.user  SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('foobar123'), password_expired = 'N' WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';

Comment: The instruction here is concise and helped me resolved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Saved me from tearing my hair. Thank you so much. Works in 2017!

Comment: I had to create /var/run/mysqld directory with owner mysql before mysqld stopped crashing. don't set 777 permissions as mentioned above!

Answer (score 12):

Here is my steps of doing this:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo killall mysqld_safe
sudo killall mysqld
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
update user set plugin="mysql_native_password";
quit;
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo kill -9 $(pgrep mysql)
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: Now after "mysql -u root" I get:
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'root' is not loaded

Comment: It sounds like you mixed up the two UPDATE queries.  Did you set plugin="root" on accident?