# Mariadb Plugin 'unix socket' is not loaded

Tags: 15.10, mysql, mariadb, sockets

After installing Mariadb on Ubuntu 15.10 I was unable to use mysql. The following error was reported: `Plugin 'unix socket' is not loaded.`

It seems that plugin table in the mysql db was empty. Why was this?

My remedy was:

```
killall mysqld_safe
killall mysqld
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
INSERT INTO mysql.plugin (name, dl) VALUES ('unix_socket', 'auth_socket');
\q
killall mysqld_safe
service mysql start
```

(With thanks to [Markus (maier-m)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1447944))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 15.10 mysql error 1524 - unix\_socket](http://askubuntu.com/questions/705458/ubuntu-15-10-mysql-error-1524-unix-socket)