# Unable to reset MySQL root password, tried everthing

Tags: permissions, password, mysql, reset

Well, let's first clarify that I have read all questions from Ask Ubuntu about this issue and I have followed all steps from the official docs:

[help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset)

[dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

So before someone suggests anything that I've probably already tried, I'm going to show what I did:

```
root@localhost:/# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
```

MySQL stopped correctly.

```
root@localhost:/# sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
[1] 3316
root@localhost:/#
```

Here I don't know if this was working or not, so I follow the steps anyway.

```
root@localhost:/# mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
root@localhost:/#
```

It seems it does not work, as service is not started. As I can't continue with the next steps I try the other method (purge).

After using:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove
sudo apt-get install
```

I try the next step:

```
root@localhost:/# mysqladmin -u root password MyNewPassword
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
root@localhost:/#
```

As this also don't work I've tried other methods mentioned on the mysql web:

So I kill mysql process as pointed there and then I use

```
root@localhost:/# mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
[1] 5267
root@localhost:/# 2017-02-01T12:47:49.250083Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2017-02-01T12:47:49.252427Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.

2017-02-01T12:47:49.254765Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.

2017-02-01T12:47:49.257045Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

[1]+  Salida 1                mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init
root@localhost:/#
```

Now is when I was getting out of options, so I also try another method mentioned here on Ask Ubuntu:

```
root@localhost:/# sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.17, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
root@localhost:/#
```

And now I'm really out of options, so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by executing this line:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld; sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

before executing this line:

```
root@localhost:/# mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```

For me, [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705458/ubuntu-15-10-mysql-error-1524-unix-socket) worked better.

I think there is a cleaner way to do this, but for me, it was a quick and efficient workaround.

Comment: thx, that did the trick ;)

Comment: It happens on mysql 5.7. When you stop the mysql service /var/run/mysqld gets removed and gets recreated when you start again the service.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get mysql to reinstall no matter what I tried, I ended up just needing to try and reset the password.

I had to go this route on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.  I spent an hour or more trying all other suggestions from MySql website to everything on SO as well as the AskUbuntu Q&A's, I finally got it working with:

**Note:** while it showed Enter password for user root, I didnt have the original password so I just entered the same password to be used as the new password.

**Note:** there was no /var/log/mysqld.log only /var/log/mysql/error.log

Also note this did not work for me:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7`

Nor did:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force mysql-server-5.5`

Make MySQL service directory.

`sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld`

Give MySQL user permission to write to the service directory.

`sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld`

Then:

1. kill the current mysqld pid
2. run mysqld with sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld &
3. run /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

   **Output from mysql_secure_installation**

   > root@myServer:~# /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
   >
   > Securing the MySQL server deployment.
   >
   > Enter password for user root:
   >
   > VALIDATE PASSWORD PLUGIN can be used to test passwords
   >   and improve security. It checks the strength of password
   >   and allows the users to set only those passwords which are
   >   secure enough. Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin?
   >
   > Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: no
   >   Using existing password for root.
   >   Change the password for root ? ((Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >
   > New password:
   >
   > Re-enter new password:
   >   By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user,
   >   allowing anyone to log into MySQL without having to have
   >   a user account created for them. This is intended only for
   >   testing, and to make the installation go a bit smoother.
   >   You should remove them before moving into a production
   >   environment.
   >
   > Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >   Success.
   >
   > Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from
   >   'localhost'. This ensures that someone cannot guess at
   >   the root password from the network.
   >
   > Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >   Success.
   >
   > By default, MySQL comes with a database named 'test' that
   >   anyone can access. This is also intended only for testing,
   >   and should be removed before moving into a production
   >   environment.
   >
   > Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >
   > - Dropping test database...
   >     Success.
   > - Removing privileges on test database...
   >     Success.
   >
   > Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes
   >   made so far will take effect immediately.
   >
   > Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >   Success.
   >
   > All done!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
# service mysql stop
# mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
# chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
# mysql -u root
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('1234') where user='root';
```

(Here, `authentication_string` holds the password field.)