# receive ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) while trying to access mysql

Tags: kubuntu, mysql, root, 21.10

The problem I have is that I cannot access `mysql` using terminal and receive the message `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. 
I searched much and found no answer to help.
 
Thanks for help.

Comment: The `root` account can only be accessed via `sudo`. Try this: `sudo mysql`

Comment: @matigo Yes, I've absolutely used =)

Comment: In that case, you have a bad password. You will need to enter the correct one. If you have forgotten the correct password, you *may* be able to reset it [following this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/878687/1222991).