# problem installing mysql-server - There is a MySQL server running

Tags: server, software-installation, mysql

i tried to replace mysql with MariaDB, removed, installed, removed, installed again mysql and i am stuck now when i try to reinstall mysql

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

with this message:

**There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!**

But there isnt any mysql server running:

> ps -ef | grep mysql
>
> xxxxx    13881 13041  0 00:59 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql

Any idea how i can solve this problem and install mysql again?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [link.](https://superuser.com/questions/840178/unable-to-remove-package-on-debian-7)
According to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1102887/548217)

The solution could be removing the following symbolic link:

`root@box{~}:la /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Feb  9 22:55 /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service -> /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`

If you get the following error:
`1524: Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded while connecting to the MySQL server`

Try the answer from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705458/ubuntu-15-10-mysql-error-1524-unix-socket/705466#705466)

Become root

`sudo su`

Stop MySQL, bypass authentication, connect as root

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot
```

Use the administrative db

`use mysql;`

Reset the root password

`update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';`

Reset authentication method

`update user set plugin="mysql_native_password";`

Exit the mysql console

`quit;`

Stop and start mysql related processes

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
kill -9 $(pgrep mysql)
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Exit su mode and try connecting to the mysql server

Comment: Okay, after removing that link i get now this: mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1524: Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded while connecting to the MySQL server

Comment: Okay, i removed that link and typed the other commands.

mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables gives me this message:

**mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.**

mysql -uroot comes up with this error message:

**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

Comment: try running the following commands: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart and then sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start. If that doesn't work then try connecting using this command: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p <password for root user>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still the same.

I could start mysql and i see it is up and running with **ps -ef | grep mysql**

`mysql    18067     1  0 00:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld`

`root     18242 12670  0 00:24 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
`

But when i try to remove/purge/install it or try to connect with **mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306...** i still get

`ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded`

Comment: sorry it didn't work...  for my last attempt try this [link](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mariadb/plugin-unix_socket-is-not-loaded-2)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but that doesnt work either. When i try to connect with **mysql -u root -p** i get again **ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded** and mysql terminates and i am back in the shell.

Maybe i should do a complete fresh install of Ubuntu on this comp...

Answer (score 0):

Got it now...

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get remove --purge mariadb*
```

and remove all mysql databases (you will be asked if you want to remove them), then I can do a fresh install of mysql-server without error messages.